# How can I view pods with kubectl and filter based on having a status of ImagePullBackOff?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'd like to do a `kubectl get pods` and filter where the pod  is in a status of `ImagePullBackOff`.

I've tried `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=waiting` and `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=ImagePullBackOff` but that returns no results.

I've had a look at the JSON output with `-o json`:

```
...
            {
                "image": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
                "imageID": "",
                "lastState": {},
                "name": "nginx",
                "ready": false,
                "restartCount": 0,
                "state": {
                    "waiting": {
                        "message": "Back-off pulling image \"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\"",
                        "reason": "ImagePullBackOff"
                    }
                }
            }
...
```

If I try target that value:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=state.waiting=ImagePullBackOff 
Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "/v1, Resource=pods" that match label selector "", field selector "state.waiting=ImagePullBackOff": field label not supported: state.waiting
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `json` output and piping through `jq`:

```
kubectl get pod -o=json | jq '.items[]|select(any( .status.containerStatuses[]; .state.waiting.reason=="ImagePullBackOff"))|.metadata.name'
```

Last chunk `|.metadata.name` means it'll list pod names instead of the entire structures.

Comment: This is an impressive use of jq! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can use command below:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,POD:metadata.name,PodIP:status.podIP,STATE:status.containerStatuses[*].state.waiting.reason | grep ImagePullBackOff
```

BTW: your command `kubectl get pods --field-selector=state.waiting=ImagePullBackOff`  fails because there is no `state.waiting` selector in kubernetes. Thats why you see `field label not supported: state.waiting` error.

As per [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) and [Field Selectors docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase):

A Pod’s status field is a PodStatus object, which has a phase field.

Here are the possible values for phase:

- Pending
- Running
- Succeeded
- Failed
- Unknown

So use [custom-columns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns) output.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the offical doc for kubernetes,

> Supported field selectors vary by Kubernetes resource type. All resource types support the metadata.name and metadata.namespace fields. Using unsupported field selectors produces an error.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#supported-fields

You can try this:

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces | grep "ImagePullBackOff" | awk '{print $2 " -n " $1}' | xargs kubectl get pod -o json
```

Or:

```
kubectl get pod -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.containerStatuses[*].state.waiting.reason=="ImagePullBackOff")].metadata.name}'
```